# Sync local repo with YAST repo

Tags: artifactory, opensuse

Could you help to create a local repo and sync it to remote YAST repo http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:/Appliances/openSUSE_13.2/
. This is to prevent the risk of the above link got removed/unavailable for build. 
I can create a local YUM repo and reposync to this remote YAST repo, but YUM repo does not support Source rpm (refer to https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Creating_YaST_installation_sources).

Another question: What is the usage of src/ in YAST repo ? Do I need *.src.rpm for build ?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [remote Yum repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/YUM+Repositories#YUMRepositories-RemoteRepositories) which will proxy the opensuse.org repository. Please notice, that a [remote repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-RemoteRepositories) in Artifactory will not actively mirror all the content of the external repository (opensuse) but will rather serve as a write through caching proxy.
Once you have the artifacts cached in Artifactory, you will be able to download them even if the external repository is removed/unavailable.